# Help: how to proof boolean algebraic identity

Tags: proof-explanation, boolean-algebra

I am stuck on this question.

> Proof the following:$$(abd+a’b+b’d+c’)(c+ab+bd) = b(a+c)(a’+c’)+d(b+c)$$

So far I could only figure out the following.

> LHS: $(abd+a’b+b’d+c’)(c+ab+bd)$
>
> 1. **Expand everything:** $$(abcd+aabbd+abbdd)+(a'bc+aa'bb+a'bbd)+(b'cd+abb'd+bb'dd)+(cc'+abc'+bc'd)$$
> 2. **Simplify idempotent terms:** $$(abcd+abd+abd)+(a'bc+0 \cdot b+a'bd)+(b'cd+a \cdot 0 \cdot d+0 \cdot d)+0+abc'+bc'd$$
>      $$=abcd+abc'+abd+a'bc+a'bd+bc'd+b'cd$$
> 3. **Factor out $b$ ($bc'd$ is left out cause it doesn't help):** $$b(acd+ac'+ad+a'c+a'd)+bc'd+b'cd$$
> 4. **Absorption ($acd+ad=ad$ and $ad+a'd=d$):** $$b(ac'+a'c+d)+bc'd+b'cd$$

---

> RHS: $b(a+c)(a’+c’)+d(b+c)$
>
> 1. **Expand everything:** $$b(aa'+ac'+a'c+cc')+bd+cd$$
>      $$=aa'b+abc'+a'bc+bcc'+bd+cd$$
> 2. **Simplify idempotent terms:** $$0 \cdot b+abc'+a'bc+b \cdot 0+bd+cd$$
>      $$=abc'+a'bc+bd+cd$$

Not sure where I can go from here. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please add some information to this question :  
these are elements from a boolean algebra like $\mathbb{F}_2$?  
if yes, is a' = a + 1 (the negation of a) ?

Comment: Hint : you don't have to go from left to right or from right to left, you can also prove that both sides are equal to a third expression.

Comment: You need to open brackets on both sides separately and show that the resulting expression is the same

Comment: It is true that $b(a+c)(a'+c')$ is equivalent to $abc' + a'bc$, but the author of this exercise wants you to prove equivalence of two expressions, not simplify the LHS.  As for simplicity, the RHS has 8 literals, but the best sum of products has 10.

Comment: @OlivierRoche I'm not sure whether they're from F2 since the question provides no additional information. But thanks for reminding me that proofing doesn't necessarily mean going left to right or right to left! :D

Comment: @VC $\mathbb{F}_2$ or not doesn't matter, it was just an example.

Comment: In your work on the LHS, you are now very close to the solution.  You have a $bd$ term and also $bc'd$.  You know what absorption does... You can then look at $bd$ and $b'cd$.  Can you simplify the latter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost there!

Let's expand what you ended up with the LHS:

$b(ac'+a'c+d)+bc'd+b'cd=$

$abc'+a'bc+bd+bc'd+b'cd$

*Absorption* ($bd+bc'd=bd$)

$abc'+a'bc+bd+b'cd$

*Factor*

$abc'+a'bc+(b+b'c)d$

*Distribution*

$abc'+a'bc+(b+b')(b+c)d$

$abc'+a'bc+1(b+c)d$

$abc'+a'bc+(b+c)d$

$abc'+a'bc+bd+cd$

Comment: Is the $(b+b')$ method a commonly seen and useful way to simplify/expand boolean algebra?

Comment: @VC Using the fact that $b + b' = 1$ is, yes ... together with the fact that $a1=a$, and $a+1=1$.  Likewise, you have that $aa'=0$, and $a0=0$, and $a+0=a$